# DataFrame.ix() in pandas - is there an option to catch situations when requested columns do not exist?

Tags: dataframe, pandas

My code reads CSV file into pandas `DataFrame` - and processes it.
The code relies on column names - uses df.ix[,] to get the columns.
Recently some column names in the CSV file were changed (without notice).
But the code was not complaining and was silently producing wrong results.
The ix[,] construct doesn't check if column exists.
If it doesn't - it simply creates it and populate with NaN.
Here is the main idea of what was going on.

```
df1=DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})   # columns 'a' & 'b'
df2=df1.ix[:,['a','c']]                    # trying to get 'a' & 'c'
print df2
       a   c
    0  1 NaN
    1  2 NaN
    2  3 NaN
```

So it doesn't produce an error or a warning.

Is there an alternative way to select specific columns with extra check that columns exist?

My current workaround is to use my own small utility function, something like this:

```
import sys, inspect

def validate_cols_or_exit(df,cols):
  """
    Exits with error message if pandas DataFrame object df 
    doesn't have all columns from the provided list of columns
    Example of usage:
      validate_cols_or_exit(mydf,['col1','col2'])
  """
  dfcols = list(df.columns)
  valid_flag = True
  for c in cols:
    if c not in dfcols:
       print "Error, non-existent DataFrame column found - ",c
       valid_flag = False
  if not valid_flag:
    print "Error, non-existent DataFrame column(s) found in function ", inspect.stack()[1][3]
    print "valid column names are:"
    print "\n".join(df.columns)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
In [3]: df1[['a', 'c']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/wesm/code/pandas/<ipython-input-3-2349e89f1bb5> in <module>()
----> 1 df1[['a', 'c']]

/home/wesm/code/pandas/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1582             if com._is_bool_indexer(key):
   1583                 key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)
-> 1584             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1585         elif isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):
   1586             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)

/home/wesm/code/pandas/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   1609             mask = indexer == -1
   1610             if mask.any():
-> 1611                 raise KeyError("No column(s) named: %s" % str(key[mask]))
   1612             result = self.reindex(columns=key)
   1613             if result.columns.name is None:

KeyError: 'No column(s) named: [c]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can constrain a DataFrame, but your helper function could be a lot simpler. (something like)

```
mismatch = set(cols).difference(set(dfcols))
    if mismatch:
        raise SystemExit('Unknown column(s): {}'.format(','.join(mismatch)))
```